# Importing and Exporting Data from Google Cloud SQL Database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am having a hard time setting up a database in Google Cloud SQL. As of right now I have database created with a table for "Students". What I don't understand is how to view the data and/or how to import data from an API into this database.

I've tried fetching all the data from an API and using INSERT in a data.sql file, but this has proven to be immensely slow and inefficient

I expect that there is a way to directly gather API data and insert it into the cloud database, but I have not found a way to do this yet.

Comment: Payton, watch one of the Cloud SQL or just plain MySQL videos on YouTube to get an understanding of the basics of SQL databases.

Comment: Hi, i need little more information about your setup. Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? Also wich API are you using? You could be using the REST API, the GCloud API.

Comment: I'm using MySQL and a REST API

Answer (score 1):

To view the data in your database you can ssh into your Cloud SQL instance following this [Quickstart for Cloud SQL for MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart) guide. To select your database when you reach [this point in the guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart#create_a_database_and_upload_data) Just use the command `USE <Your database name>;` to select the database that you already created. Then you can do a `SELECT * FROM <yourTable>;` to see your data.

After that in order to use the Cloud SQL REST API to import data into your database, you can follow this [Importing data into Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing) guide. Here you will be able to import your data.sql from a bucket (which is the fastest way to import data into your database).

To export data from your database you can also follow this [Exporting data from Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting) guide.